# GKE - Can I change the CNI plugin?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE uses Calico for networking by default. Is there an option to use some other CNI plugin ?

Answer (score 3):

No, GKE does not offer such option, you have to use the provided Calico.